# Reading avi file, getting single frames with cv2.VideoCapture and video.read, and the png files of the single frames are much bigger than the avi

Tags: size, png, frame, opencv, avi, python

I'm reading an avi file with approx 2MB size, 301 frames, 20 frames/sec (15 sec long video) and a size of 1024 * 1096 per frame.

When I'm reading the single frames with cv2 and resaving them in original size as png, then I'm getting a size of approx 600KB per picture/frame. So, I have in total 301 * 600KB = 181MB (original avi had 2MB).

Any idea why this is happening and how to reduce the file size of the single frames without changing the resolution? Idea is to somehow generate single frames from the original video, do detections with CNN and to resave the original video again with included detections and the output video shall be somehow very similar to input video (approx same file size, must not be avi format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PNG files or single frames are in the most cases always larger than the original video file (compressed in the most cases by a codec https://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php). Use for example the following command on Linux to create a compressed avi:
`ffmpeg -i FramePicName%d.png -vcodec libx264 -f avi aviFileName`
You can get the used codec to create the original video file by the following python cv2 code

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)`
`fourcc = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC) # or cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC`
`"".join([chr((int(fourcc) >> 8 * i) & 0xFF) for i in range(4)])`